# Error fuel php curl, Failed to connect to localhost port 1080:Connection refused

Tags: git, bash, fuelphp

```
localhost@Abliter MINGW64 /c/wamp/www
$ curl get.fuelphp.com/oil | sh
  % Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
                                 Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed
  0     0    0     0    0     0      0      0 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:--     0
curl: (7) Failed to connect to localhost port 1080: Connection refused
```

Answer (score 0):

Port `1080` ist the standard port for SOCKS proxies. So it seems you configured your system / curl to use `localhost` as SOCKS proxy, but you have no SOCKS proxy running on `localhost`, hence the error message.

Comment: Do I need to download SOCKS proxy?

Comment: Only if you want to use a SOCKS proxy for your requests. Most probably you do not want to if you don't even know what it means.

Comment: how to have SOCKS proxy?

Comment: I don't know how SOCKS proxy is, so how to connect to localhost port 1080?

Comment: I have project that will past tomorrow, and this one make my work stop

Comment: As I said, turn off SOCKS proxy usage of curl that you enabled. Alternatively simple download the oil script you need via Browser instead of with `curl`. Besides that, this question is off-topic alltogether on StackOvervlow, it would be better suited on SuperUser.